# MongoDB find records with empty array or array match

Tags: mongodb

I have a set of records like the following:

```
[ 
  { title: 'foo', members: [ 'a', 'b' ] },
  { title: 'bar', members: [] },
  { title: 'fiz', members: [ 'b' ] }
]
```

The `members` prop is used for restricting certain records so what I'm hoping to do is check the property and if empty or doesn't exist OR it contains the member return the item.

For example:

- User `a` would get back `foo` (is a member) and `bar` (no member restrictions)
- User `b` would get all three because they are a member on `0` and `2` and no member restrictions are set on on `1`

Comment: Try  `var user = 'a'; db.collection.distinct('title', { '$or': [
        { 'members': user },
        { 'members.0': { '$exists': false } }
] });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "members.0": {
        $exists: false
      }
    },
    {
      "members": "User"
    }
  ]
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8vUx8VblBrU)

or

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $size: "$members"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "members": "User"
    }
  ]
})
```